# Page Won't Load Using JQuery .ready()

Tags: jquery, google-visualization, document-ready

It's not really an issue as much as I'm curious. I always like to use the JQuery .ready() function before calling functions that are supposed to start on page load, but for some reason combining these two causes my page to not load-- no errors in the log and functions are not being called. Here is an example of where this is happening:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(loadHeader);

});
```

Is there a problem with using a callback inside of the .ready() function? The page just appears to be hanging. Changing my code to exclude the .ready() seems to make everything work just fine.

```
  google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
  google.setOnLoadCallback(loadHeader);
```

Thank you!

Comment: what would be the purpose of putting the google loader inside jQuery `ready` in the first place? It's not documented that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are putting the google.load inside a jquery.ready, it is probably considered dynamic loading.  And according to the google.load [documentation](https://developers.google.com/loader/#GoogleLoad) 
you have to pass a callback in order to perform dynamic loading. "To load the API dynamically, pass a callback option in the third parameter."

```
function loadApi() {
    google.load("visualization", "1", {"callback" : pageLoaded});
}
```